# connect uiview to uiviewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiview, uiviewcontroller

i try to create 2 players game for the ipad, the game should be a multiplayer game (one player vs other player on the same device). now, i need to add for my main viewcontroller two uiviews that each one will be connected to another viewcontroller. i create a 2 uiviewcontroller named viewcontrollerA and viewcontrollerB and each one of then will be on a half size from the screen. i drag to my xib file 2 uiview and connects then to the outlets that i declare in my mainview.h (the outlets are: IBOutlet uiviewcontrollerA *viewA). the problem is when i try to run the app i got stack overflow. can anyone please explain me how do i do the connection right?
thanks!

Comment: 1) Why not make the two views part of the main view controller?  2) What exception do you get and what does the stack trace look like?  (Add an exception breakpoint if you need to in order to find this out.)  3) What is your code doing when the exception occurs?

Comment: i just want to know how to connect between uiview and a viewcontroller

Comment: The problem with that is that there are a bunch of different ways and, without knowing what you're already trying to do, it's not really possible to tell you what's right for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i could understand your question which is (how to connect between uiview and a viewcontroller )
you need to check the identity inspecter in xcode where you're on the storyboard and just select the viewController of A or B (as you named your viewControllers)

like the image bellow [image]